# Select text in regex between 2 strings

Tags: regex

I have the following line :

```
3EAM7A 1 3 EI AMANDINE MRV SHP 70 W 0 SH3-A1 1 SHP 70W OVOIDE AI E27 SON PIA PLUS
```

I'd like to get the string : `EI AMANDINE MRV SHP 70 W`. So I decided to select the strings between `1` (can also be `2`, `3` or `99`) and `0` (can also be `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` or `5`).
I tried :

```
(0|1|2|3|99)(.*)(0|1|2|3|4|5)
```

But I have this result :

```
EAM7A 1 3 EI AMANDINE MRV SHP 70 W 0 SH3-A1 1 SHP 70W OVOIDE AI E
```

that is not what I want to obtain.

Do you have an idea in regex to make that selection work ?
Thanks !

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you for the answers ! It helps me a lot and you learned me different tricks to do so. Thanks again !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close! Try this:

```
\b(?:0|1|2|3|99) ([^0|1|2|3|99].*?) (?:0|1|2|3|4|5)\b
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iX6oE1/8)

Answer (score 2):

I think that you want to match "word" 4 to 9?

Your desired match will be in group 1

```
^(\S+\s){3}((\S+\s){6})
```

Enable the multiline option if you have a whole file of subject strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
\s(?:[0-3]|99)\s([A-Z].*?)\b(?:[0-5])\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iX6oE1/5)

and get string by group $1. Or if your language support look around, try:

```
(?<=\s[0-3]\s|99)[A-Z].+?(?=\s[0-5]\s)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iX6oE1/7)

to get match directly.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that is based on matching all initial `space` + `digit` sequences:

```
\b(?:(?:[0-3]|99)\b\s*)+(.*?)\s*\b(?:[0-5])\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sS0tA5/5)

The result is in Group 1. 
With `\b(?:(?:[0-3]|99)\b\s*)+` the rightmost number from the allowed leading set is picked.

Comment: Your regular expression incorrectly captures `EI AMANDINE MRV SHP 70 W` if the number before it is not in the set 0,1,2,3,99

Comment: @iismathwizard: I see, I added support for any `space` + `number` after the first number from the set.

Comment: why? Op clearly stated the number will only be in the set `[0-3|99]`

Comment: I fixed it. And not `[0-3|99]`, but `([0-3]|99)`.

Comment: @Whoever downvoted without a commet: you will have -1. That is why when downvoting, you need to declare what you did not like.

Comment: mb with the [0-3|99]. I did mean ([0-3]|99) though. Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex :

```
(?:(?:[0-3]|99)\s)+(.*?)\s(?:[0-5])\s
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/iX6oE1/6

Also note that for matching a range of number you can use a character class instead of multiple OR.

Comment: op doesn't want to capture all of that. `EI AMANDINE MRV SHP 70 W`

Comment: @iismathwizard Yep, fixed!

Comment: Actually, it's still wrong. it captures the `3` just before the string.